# Codelite/Mingw runs a test build instead of a file that I want it to

Tags: mingw, codelite

Before I begin asking my question, I have looked into this error but I haven't been able to have any luck into solving my problem. I believe it should be a simple fix but I haven't quite got it yet.

I am currently running an error (sorta) in my codelite when I begin to run my build for my work. Keep in mind I am running the current version of codelite, which is 12.0.15 and with tdm64-gcc. Whenever I begin to run, all it prints out is a simple "hello world" instead of running a project that I created. I have noticed that whenever I run, It opens a different file instead of the file I originally want it to run.

c:\Users\Name\Documents\cppsample\test\debug\test.exe && pause

This is not running on the file in which I want to run it in whatsoever. So my question is, how can I make codelite run the proper file that I want it to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CodeLite workspace can contain multiple projects, but only one of them is
*the active project*. When you select **Build** -> **Build project**, or **Build** -> **Run**, from
the menu bar, you build and/or run *the active project*.

The first project that you create in a workspace becomes the active project automatically and thereafter
any other project that you create only becomes the active project if *you make it* the
active project.

The project that you are trying to build and run is not the active the project. Make
it the active project by selecting its name in the Workspace tree-view, right-click, then
select **Make active** from the menu. When it is the active project its name will be
***italicised and bold*** in the Workspace tree-view.